# SQL 2 left outer joins on same table

Tags: sql, join, left-join, outer-join

I'm doing 2 joins on the same table and I want the following results:

```
chnl_ptnr_key type1_ky type2_ky
------------- -------- --------
1             1        null
1             2        null
1             null     3
1             null     4
```

But instead I'm getting

```
chnl_ptnr_key type1_ky type2_ky
------------- -------- --------
1             1        3
1             2        3
1             2        3
1             2        4
```

My query is:

```
SELECT cp.chnl_ptnr_ky, cpmap1.ky as type1_ky, cpmap2.ky as type2_ky
FROM chnl_ptnr cp
LEFT OUTER JOIN chnl_ptnr_oos_map cpmap1 on (cp.chnl_ptnr_ky = cpmap1.chnl_ptnr_ky and cpmap1.typ = 'TYPE1')
LEFT OUTER JOIN chnl_ptnr_oos_map cpmap2 on (cp.chnl_ptnr_ky = cpmap2.chnl_ptnr_ky and cpmap2.typ = 'TYPE2')
WHERE cp.chnl_ptnr_ky = '1111'
```

Can someone help me to change this query so I get nulls in `type1_ky` and `type2_ky` where the row is being returned from the other join?
I need this format because I'm attempting to use it for an iBATIS map.

Many thanks

Comment: what is your schema for `chnl_ptnr` and `chnl_ptnr_oos_map`?

Comment: Very cryptic names and not providing the data of the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the results of the first `LEFT JOIN` are (1,1) and (1,2).  As there are no (1,NULL) records, there will be no (1,NULL,?) records after the next `LEFT JOIN`.

You probably need a UNION in there somewhere...

```
SELECT  cp.chnl_ptnr_ky, cpmap1.ky as type1_ky,  NULL AS type2_ky
FROM chnl_ptnr cp
LEFT OUTER JOIN chnl_ptnr_oos_map cpmap1 on (cp.chnl_ptnr_ky = cpmap1.chnl_ptnr_ky and     cpmap1.typ = 'TYPE1')
WHERE cp.chnl_ptnr_ky = '1111'

UNION ALL

SELECT  cp.chnl_ptnr_ky, NULL,  cpmap2.ky as type2_ky
FROM chnl_ptnr cp
LEFT OUTER JOIN chnl_ptnr_oos_map cpmap2 on (cp.chnl_ptnr_ky = cpmap2.chnl_ptnr_ky   and      cpmap2.typ = 'TYPE2')
WHERE cp.chnl_ptnr_ky = '1111'
```

Comment: ah this works thanks - i was trying something similar earlier but i was missing the null as column name part.

Comment: @ender: Please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer formally if it worked for you. And also please do the same in your other questions.